# Transpose dict of dicts without nans

Tags: python, dictionary

```
users = {"Angelica": {"Blues Traveler": 3.5, "Broken Bells": 2.0, "Norah
Jones": 4.5, "Phoenix": 5.0, "Slightly Stoopid": 1.5, "Pantera": 2.5,
"Metallica": 2.0}, "Bill":{"Blues Traveler": 2.0, "Broken Bells": 3.5,
"Deadmau5": 4.0, "Phoenix": 2.0, "Slightly Stoopid": 3.5, "Metallica": 3.0,
"Norah Jones": 5.0}}

pd.DataFrame(users).transpose().to_dict()
>>>{'Blues Traveler': {'Angelica': 3.5, 'Bill': 2.0}, 'Broken Bells':
{'Angelica': 2.0, 'Bill': 3.5}, 'Deadmau5': {'Angelica': **nan**, 'Bill':
4.0}, 'Metallica': {'Angelica': 2.0, 'Bill': 3.0}, 'Norah Jones':
{'Angelica': 4.5, 'Bill': 5.0}, 'Pantera': {'Angelica': 2.5, 'Bill':
**nan**}, 'Phoenix': {'Angelica': 5.0, 'Bill': 2.0}, 'Slightly Stoopid':
{'Angelica': 1.5, 'Bill': 3.5}}
```

I would like a dict where all the keys and values from the inner dicts are removed when the values are **nan**: i.e. 'Angelica': **nan** and 'Bill': **nan**.

My code:

```
for key in pd.DataFrame(users).transpose().to_dict():
    for k in pd.DataFrame(users).transpose().to_dict()[key]:
        if math.isnan(pd.DataFrame(users).transpose().to_dict()[key][k]) == False:
            listA.append((key, (k, pd.DataFrame(users).transpose().to_dict()
                                [key][k])))
```

Desired output without the values:

```
>>>{'Blues Traveler': {'Angelica': 3.5, 'Bill': 2.0}, 'Broken Bells':
{'Angelica': 2.0, 'Bill': 3.5}, 'Deadmau5': {'Bill': 4.0}, 'Metallica':
{'Angelica': 2.0, 'Bill': 3.0}, 'Norah Jones': {'Angelica': 4.5, 'Bill':
5.0}, 'Pantera': {'Angelica': 2.5, 'Phoenix': {'Angelica': 5.0, 'Bill':
2.0}, 'Slightly Stoopid': {'Angelica': 1.5, 'Bill': 3.5}}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code and the output you're getting.

Comment: You also should prepare a specific example of what output you are trying to get

Comment: for key in pd.DataFrame(users).transpose().to_dict():
    for k in pd.DataFrame(users).transpose().to_dict()[key]:
        if math.isnan(pd.DataFrame(users).transpose().to_dict()[key][k]) == False:
            listA.append((key,(k, pd.DataFrame(users).transpose().to_dict()[key][k])))

Comment: I am unable to edit the question for some reason. The desired output is the last line (>>>{'Blues Traveler':...) without 'Angelica': nan and 'Bill': nan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `defaultdict` for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def transpose(dct):
    d = defaultdict(dict)
    for key1, inner in dct.items():
        for key2, value in inner.items():
            d[key2][key1] = value
    return d
```

Comment: nice but people usually prefer `dct.iteritems()`

Comment: @JustinHarris: In Python 3, `iteritems` doesn't exist any more, and `items` (and `values` and `keys`) return "dictionary view" objects that are iterable without requiring making a copy of all the dictionary's data. You're right that for Python 2, `iteritems` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your output dictionary as:

```
output = {}
for k, v in pd.DataFrame(users).transpose().to_dict().items():
    inner = {}
    for m, n in v.items():
        if not math.isnan(n):
            inner[m] = n
    output[k] = inner
```